How to check at compile time for the existence of a global-scope function accepting given argument types?
What (I think) I need
How can I define a type trait that checks whether, for a type T, the function ::foo(T) is declared?
What I'm finding hard, is to have ::foo in SFINAE friendly way. For instance, if the compiler has got to the point where the following is defined,
template<typename T>
void f(T t) { foo(t); }

it's prefectly fine if no foo whatsover has been seen so far.
But as soon as I change foo to ::foo, then I get a hard error.
The use case (in case you think I don't need the above)
I have a customization point like this:
// this is in Foo.hpp
namespace foos {
inline constexpr struct Foo {
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<AdlFooable<std::decay_t<T>>::value, int> = 0>
    constexpr bool operator()(T const& x) const {
        return foo(x);
    }
} foo{};
}

that allows customizing the behavior of a call to foos::foo by defining an ADL foo overload for the desired type.
The definition of the trait is straightforward:
// this is in Foo.hpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct AdlFooable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct AdlFooable<T, std::void_t<decltype(foo(std::declval<T const&>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};

Given that, if one defines
// this is in Bar.hpp
namespace bar {
    struct Bar {};
    bool foo(bar::Bar);
}

then a call to
// other includes
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include "Bar.hpp"
bool b = foos::foo(bar::Bar{});

works as expected, with foos::foo routing the call to bar::foo(bar::Bar), which is found via ADL. And this works well regardless of the order of the two #includes, which is good, because they might be included in either order, if // other includes transitively includes them.
So far so good.
What I don't really like of this approach, is that one could mistakenly define, instead of the second snippet above, the following,
// this is in Bar.hpp
namespace bar {
    struct Bar {};
}
bool foo(bar::Bar);

with foo in global scope.
In this case, if the #include "Bar.hpp" happens to come before #include "Foo.hpp", the code program will work, because the body of Foo::operator() will pick ::foo(bar::Bar) by ordinary lookup.
But as soon as the order of the #includes happens to be reversed, then the code breaks.
Yes, the bug is in defining foo(bar::Bar) in global namespace, but I think it's also a bug that it can pass unnoticed by pure chance.
That's why I would like to change the type trait to express that "an unqualified call to foo(T) is found, but not via ordinary lookup", or, more directly, "foo(std::declval<T>()) must compile, but ::foo(std::declval<T>()) must not compile".
A non-solution for those who are curious
After I accepted the answer, I have re-read relevant parts of Josuttis' C++ Templates - The Complete Guide and found that ADL can be inhibited by a mean other than qualifying the function, i.e. wrapping the name of the unqualified function in parenthesis, e.g. while foo(args...) undergoes ADL, (foo)(args...) doesn't!
Unfortunately, that just means that the name foo is looked up as if it was fully qualified (I presume with the current namespace), and so the attempt fails the same way as described above.

Can you use requires from C++20?

You have a traits for foo(T), you can expend it for ::foo(T), then AdlFooAble<T>::value && !GlobalFooAble::value.

@Jarod42 ::foo doesn't seem to be SFINAE friendly https://godbolt.org/z/vnhsh6d37 or am I misunderstanding your comment?

@Jarod42, no, C++17, unfortunately.

@cigien, yeah, that's my difficulty: even if the actual type plugged in T is not known when you define the GlobalFooable trait, ::foo lookup doesn't seem to be delayed as foo does. I guess this is just how the language works, and I might ask another question with language-lawyer tag to ask specifically about what part of the standard determines this behavior, but here I'm looking for a solution/workaround.

You need a dummy ::foo Demo.

My bad, it doesn't work with ::foo(bar::Bar) declared after the traits :-/

The ordinary way to do this is to call the customization implementation only via ADL. So the overload ::foo(bar::Bar) is not considered in any case, regardless of include order.
And the way to do this is to include a poison pill:
namespace foos {
namespace detail {
void foo() = delete;
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T const& x) const -> decltype(foo(x)) {
        return foo(x);
    }
};
}
inline constexpr detail::Foo foo{};
}

The ordinary lookup of foo will find foos::detail::foo which will not work. It cannot examine the global scope. Therefore, the foo call will only lookup via ADL.

Edit:
This actually tells you how to form a trait that foo(x) is only callable by ADL, the nominal question. And that is, if foos::foo(x) is callable with this implementation, then foo(x) is callable via ADL only.

Other than hiding a bit the name Foo because foos::foo is the one that is meant to be used, is there a reason why you have made use of the namespace detail?

It is not relevant in this simple example, but the most functional reason for putting the cust. point and poison pill in a sub-namespace is to not interfere with the foo() functions available in foos... foos might be the typical namespace for the library, which might define types, which might also want an ADL foo which would live in foos. Putting the poison pill into that overload set has the potential to interfere, depending on the signature of the cust. point.

I don't think I understand your point yet. If foo exists as an object in namespace foos {, how can other foos functions exist in namespace foos {?

That's probably because you're not in my head and I haven't explained it well enough. :) First, because the customization point name and the ADL name are the same (you could imagine foo calls do_foo by ADL and this makes the implementation easier, but using the same name is both typical and easy for users to remember)... if we had no sub-namespace, we would have our poison pill in foos and our object in foos both named foo, but different kinds of entities (one a function, one an object) which is not allowed. That's enough to say the sub-namespace is required.

Second, and what I was referring to above, if our poison pill was in foos named foo (e.g. if we used a different customization point name, foos::call_foo which called foo via ADL), an unqualified lookup could find other foo overloads inside that namespace (e.g. implementations for types in the foos library). Those overloads may be viable, even if they would not have been found by ADL. And then we might make a non-ADL call.

Third, if you had other types in foos, you would still run into the same "kinds of entity" problem, unless you additionally put the object foo inside an inline namespace (different from detail), which I didn't above. One then defines foo implementations in that library as hidden friends, e.g. struct T { friend bool foo(T) { ...} }. The unqualified foo call in Foo will find them. Calls foos::foo(...) or using foos::foo; foo(...) and using namespace foos; foo(...) will call through the object. Unqualified calls foo(T()) will call via ADL. https://godbolt.org/z/xTssEGbTb
